# Passing Data Model to Foreground Service

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a foreground service which I trigger on my Splash Activity

```
Intent StartServiceIntent;
StartServiceIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(PagesService));

StartServiceIntent.PutExtra("Table", LINKMODEL);

Log.Info("101028", "Connectted");
StartService(StartServiceIntent);
```

At point where I am using `PutExtra`, I want to send a data model items  in a list `List<LINKMODEL>` to the service, the following data model

```
public class LINKMODEL
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }       
    }
```

It seems like the service only accepts few parameters such as array etc,

How do I send a whole model to the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do it is using Newtonsoft Json Nuget Package.

1.Install the Newtonsoft JSON package in case you don't have it

`Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 11.0.1`

2.When you have to send your object from one activity to another serialize your obj to JSON string.

`string toSend = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourModelobj);`

3.Pass it into the intent as a string

4.After receiving it on the other activity deserialize it and use it however you need.

`LINKMODEL localDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LINKMODEL>(intentData);`

You can also do this on List<> obj's

Goodluck!

Comment: Wow, thanks, not sure why i didn't think of that :)

Comment: Sure! I would suggest you mark it up so if someone else is looking for it they can find it  aswell @aliusman

Comment: Done, marked as answer already